# MySQL if statement for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement

I have to deal with already developed system where we have users that are set into a mysql table users. There is a second table called users_preferences. That table stores user privacy settings. It's all ok except for that it is not necessary to have a record for every user. If there is no record, i have to assume that the user is public. This is where the problem is - i'm trying to search in the users table, based on the users_preferences table. What I have so far is:

```
SELECT users.id AS id, users.username AS username, users.avatar AS avatar,  IF(users_preferences.privacyControls is null OR users_preferences.privacy = 0), 0, 1) AS userPrivacy 
FROM users, users_preferences 
WHERE users_preferences.userid = users.id AND userPrivacy = 0 AND users.username LIKE '%demo_user%'
```

That query is not valid and throws an error, but it will give you a basic idea what i want to do - I want to select those users that have set users_preferences.privacy = 0 (OR there is no such record).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should search Left join, it will let you do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  users.id AS id,
  users.username AS username,
  users.avatar AS avatar,
  IFNULL(users_preferences.privacyControls, 0) AS userPrivacy
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN users_preferences ON users_preferences.userid = users.id
WHERE
  IFNULL(users_preferences.privacyControls, 0) = 0
  AND users.username LIKE '%demo_user%'
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'userPrivacy' in 'where clause' It shows that, but when i remove all the WHERE clauses it is successful and shows the results, but if I set WHERE userPrivacy = 0 it dies. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.username, a.avatar
FROM Users a LEFT JOIN Users_Preferences b ON
        a.ID = b.userID
WHERE   (b.userPrivacy = 0 OR b.userID IS NULL) AND
        a.Username LIKE '%demo_user%'
```

You can now omit `userPrivacy` since you are filtering `userPrivacy` to 0. It is already understood that the result above are all public users. Or you can do it like this.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.username, a.avatar, 'PUBLIC USER' as userPrivacy
FROM Users a LEFT JOIN Users_Preferences b ON
        a.ID = b.userID
WHERE   (b.userPrivacy = 0 OR b.userID IS NULL) AND
        a.Username LIKE '%demo_user%'
```